# Set custom rolling date range for Google Data Studio

Tags: google-data-studio

Our company reports on data from the 21st of each month to the 20th of the next month. Is there a way I can set an Advanced date range filter in Data Studio to accomplish this? One that I don't have to manually go and update each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, there is a workaround through a ***Google Sheet*** and a blend in ***Google Data Studio***.

1. Make a copy of [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-09SgAQaXWzF230xyPbnLpNMb91IbSH5b2rTJYD9ggw/), and edit the **Start Date** and **End Date** formulas according to your needs. They are dynamic DATEVALUE formulas built so that they will change every month. On the **Date** column there is an ARRAYFORMULA that extracts all the dates in our desired date range.
2. Then go to Data Studio, connect this spreadsheet as a data source and build a table with the Date as a dimension, and - an important aspect - no date range dimension assigned.
3. The next step is to create a table with your regular data source, and your desired metrics, and for this one make sure you have a date range dimension assigned.
4. Blend the two and you will have the data just for your custom range.

The blend has to have the **Google Sheet on the left** (with the Date as a dimension & no date range) and **the regular data source on the right**, with all your desired metrics, the Date as a dimension, and the date range set to Auto (as below). The condition through which they’re blended is a **left outer join** based on the Date dimension.

[image: Blend for Custom Rolling Date Range For Google Data Studio]

What results is exactly what you need - a custom rolling date range. Next month it will reset according to the new month's values as defined in the Google Sheets formula.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you!